# How to open a text file in Linux Text Editor using QProcess in Qt

Tags: qt

I'm trying to open a file in text editor using qt by the QProcess Class... on windows it worked but on Linux i'm facing problems. my code is:

```
QProcess proc;
proc.startDetached("test",QStringList() << "-n 1");
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is `test` binary or script? If binary have you compiled it also for `linux`, if it's a script, do you have the interpreter in `linux`. Please clarify better the problem.

Comment: text is a text file i created in the output directory of the project

Comment: I want to open this text file using Text Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `startDetached` expects program to be executed, I tried opening with `vi` and it works. You want to open process `test` in `linux` that does not exists. Probably for `win32` `QProcess` automatically opens with best text editor.

```
QProcess proc;
proc.startDetached("vi test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

well it worked also better by using gedit instead of vi